# Error: Unable to correct dependencies

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies

OS and version : Debian 8

Arch : 64 bit

I am trying to update packages but I get the following error:

```
# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.29) but 2.31-4 is installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.29) but 2.31-4 is installed
 libc6 : Depends: libnss-nisplus but it is not installable
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.28-8) but 2.31-4 is installed
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.31) but 2.28-8 is installed
           Depends: libc-l10n (> 2.31) but 2.28-8 is installed
 openssh-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:8.3p1-1) but 1:6.7p1-5+deb8u8 is installed
                  Depends: runit-helper (>= 2.8.14~) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libcom-err2 (>= 1.43.9) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.17) but 1.12.1+dfsg-19+deb8u5 is installed
                  Depends: libkrb5-3 (>= 1.13~alpha1+dfsg) but 1.12.1+dfsg-19+deb8u5 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

When I try the command, `apt-get -f install`, I get the below error:

```
# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.29) but 2.31-4 is installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.29) but 2.31-4 is installed
 libc6 : Depends: libnss-nisplus but it is not installable
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.28-8) but 2.31-4 is installed
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.31) but 2.28-8 is installed
           Depends: libc-l10n (> 2.31) but 2.28-8 is installed
 openssh-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:8.3p1-1) but 1:6.7p1-5+deb8u8 is installed
                  Depends: runit-helper (>= 2.8.14~) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libcom-err2 (>= 1.43.9) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.17) but 1.12.1+dfsg-19+deb8u5 is installed
                  Depends: libkrb5-3 (>= 1.13~alpha1+dfsg) but 1.12.1+dfsg-19+deb8u5 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

My **sources.list** file:

```
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ jessie-updates main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
```

Output of apt-cache policy:

```
# apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ jessie-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=label=Debian,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable-updates,n=jessie-updates,l=Debian,c=main
     origin mirrors.kernel.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=8,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ jessie/main Translation-en
 500 http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
     release v=8.11,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=main
     origin mirrors.kernel.org
Pinned packages:
     nginx -> (not found)
```

I am stuck here. Kindly help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what led up to this? The system has been partially upgraded to Debian testing (Debian 11), and it’s ended up with mis-matched `libc6` and `locales` packages (the latter from some point during the development of Debian 10).

Comment: There is some issue with Nginx serving https, so I issued the command apt-get update and apt-get upgrade and then I got this error.

Comment: Do you know why the testing repository was added? Could you [edit] your question to add the output of `apt-cache policy`?

Comment: I think it was added by some of my team members. I have edited the question now.

Comment: The problem isn't held packages, the problem is that you're trying to combine different distribution repositories and that  is *heavily contraindicated*.

Comment: ... The problem is *also* that debian jessie has been EOL for over two years.

Comment: @Shadur Jessie reached EOL earlier this year, and is still supported under [the ELTS program](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Extended).

Answer (score 1):

Your system has a badly mixed-up set of packages from various stages of in-development versions of Debian. For example, its `libc6` package is the version currently in testing (that will become Debian 11), its `locales` package is an old version from some point in the development of Debian 10...

To get things back into some semblance of order, you’ll have to choose a target *release*, and switch to that. Given that the system is supposed to be on Debian 8, and your `apt` is configured accordingly (given the output of `apt-cache policy`), you’d be better off starting with either Debian 8 or Debian 9. Let’s assume Debian 8:

- remove the `testing` entries from `/etc/apt/sources.list`;
- tell `apt` to downgrade to Debian 8:

  ```
  printf "Package: *\n Pin: release o=Debian n=jessie\n Pin-Priority: 1001\n" > /etc/apt/preferences.d/jessie
  ```
- downgrade by “upgrading”:

  ```
  apt-get update
  apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```

**Before your start doing this** you should check with your team-mates to determine why the testing repositories were added in the first place; presumably there’s some package which was pulled from there intentionally.

Once you’re back on Debian 8, you should [add the ELTS repositories](https://deb.freexian.com/extended-lts/docs/how-to-use-extended-lts/) (and if you plan on continuing to use this, [consider becoming a sponsor](https://deb.freexian.com/extended-lts/)), or upgrade [to Debian 9](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/installmanual) and perhaps then even [to Debian 10](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/installmanual).

Comment: Thank you, but I still get the dependency error when I try to use dist-upgrade.

Comment: OK, so your system is too badly broken for `dist-upgrade` to figure things out on its own. You’ll need to help `apt install -f` fix things manually first... Or re-install, which would probably take less time if you have backups.

Comment: Finally fixed the dependency issue by forcefully installing the Jessie packages ( one by one ) over the testing packages. Then I was able to use apt-get update and apt-get upgrade. Thank you so much for your guidance and help. I will do a dist-upgrade now.

Answer (score 0):

... Put bluntly, your system is badly dated.

'testing' is the static name of the staging repository -- the repository that will become the next 'stable' version.

At this point in time, that would be Bullseye - debian 11. 'Jessie' is debian 8, which has been discontinued [in 2018][1] and fell out of even long term support back in July.

I *suspect* that this line was added back when Jessie was still stable and someone wanted a couple of newer packages than were available. This particular method for that is heavily contraindicated and you've just discovered why.

Fortunately, *hopefully*, it hasn't already installed anything, so by simply removing the lines containing 'testing' from the `sources.list` you can make the error go away, but as I've said before, Debian 8 has been discontinued and has not received any kind of updates other than critical security fixes for almost two years now, and not even that anymore for the past three months.

Of course, this won't solve your current problem; for that I suspect you'll have to at least *start* by dist-upgrading to the current stable version (10) because I don't think you'll be able to get support for an nginx version that probably dates from around 2016.

Comment: Packages have already been installed from testing, see the error messages.

Comment: ... yeah, okay, then they're and is going to have to dist-upgrade and hope *that* works.

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend that *at all*, the system is partially on current testing so the only `dist-upgrade` target is testing.

Comment: I misedited my previous comment and omitted the word 'hosed' from the sentence. I wouldn't recommend it either in any normal case, but I don't think there's any other way that might un-break their current setup. The alternative is to set up an entirely new system, copy the websites and configs over, and replace it that way.